# ofstream does not print out newline to txt in Windows7

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have some issue when I want to print out `\n` I'm using `endl` for that. And the problem is when I run the code on Windows7 it won't print out the newline. But it will print out newline in Ubuntu. Both OS is using the same compiler GNU g++.

So I wonder if there are some different way to print newline to file in Windows?

```
void translate(ofstream &out, const string &line, map<string, string> m)
{
   stringstream ss(line);
   string word;
   while(ss >> word)
   {
      if(m[word].size() == 0)
         out << "A";
      else
         out << m[word] << " ";
   }
   out << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, compilable program that I can paste into my editor and try. (Also provide compiler and compiler version.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outputting either '\n' or using endl will result in the exact same content (the only difference is endl also flushes).  When that \n character is written, if the file is in "text mode", the runtime library converts it to the platform's native mechanism to indicate lines.  On unix, this is unnecessary because that mechanism is a \n byte.  On Windows, that \n becomes \r\n (carriage return, line feed).  I suspect you know all of this, but I'm reviewing it just in case.

In short, as long as your runtime library is setup for Windows, the code you have will work as you expect.  I suspect you are using cygwin's g++, or some other g++ port, that is not setup for Windows-style lines, even in text mode.  Some editors will not correctly interpret that untranslated \n.

Comment: you guessed right, I'm using cygwin's g++. Tried to open the file again with notepad++ instead, and saw that the data was output correct. I'm going to mark this as answer as soon the ticker goes down

Comment: @starcom: I can't recall how cygwin's g++'s runtime library is setup, but I do remember that there's an option (early in initial installation) to configure cygwin to use either unix-style or Windows-style lines.